# In MineCraft PC, how do you make a permanent name tag?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I noticed that when you put a name tag on a mob in Minecraft PC, it disappears when your cursor isn't hovering over it. Is there any way for you to have a permanent name tag in MineCraft PC?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with the `CustomNameVisible` tag, for which you will need to use commands to apply. For example, to summon a creeper with a constantly shown name:

```
/summon Creeper ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"Carl",CustomNameVisible:1}
```

Or to add it to an already existing named creeper:

```
/entitydata @e[type=Creeper,c=1] {CustomNameVisible:1}
```